# Sikuli with selenium Grid & Maven

Tags: maven, selenium, webdriver, sikuli

Can i Use sikuli with selenium Grid ? If remote machine will have sikuli libraries ?

Other thing:
I cant find maven dependecies for org.sikuli.script on
http://mvnrepository.com/
 is there any other way to include jar into maven ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Sikuli is that it's not going to work on headless machines. You can read more [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/239356).

There have been some attempts to solve that problem, you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26032780/1119381).

Answer (score 0):

Yes Sikuli Maven dependency for sikuli 1.1.0 are not visible on Maven Central repository. But you can use pom.xml as follows: It worked for me: this pom.xml is for Sikuli with testng framework:

```
  <repositories>
        <repository>
      <!-- OSSRH: com.sikulix -->
           <name>com.sikulix</name>
           <id>com.sikulix</id>
           <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
           <layout>default</layout>
           <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>3.8.1</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
     <version>6.8</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency> 
       <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
       <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>          
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.testngorg.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.5</source>
            <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>    
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <siuteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>testng-customsuite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </siuteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>    
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

'