# wmctrl not executable while running sikulix script in headless mode

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, sikuli, xvfb

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 lts and sikulix 1.1.0.

while running sikulix script in the ordinary way it's working great, but when i'm trying to use Xvfb [just like suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032706/how-to-get-sikuli-working-in-headless-mode), it's says that there is no wmctrl installed. and thats not true, this is the output in shell:

```
running SikuliX: -Xmx512M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsikuli.FromCommandLine
-jar ./sikulix.jar -r ../sikuliscripts/script.sikuli
[info] runcmd: lsb_release -i -r -s 
[error] RunTimeIDE:  *** terminating: command 'wmctrl' is not executable
please check the Availability!
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Having exactly same problem with Sikuli 1.1.0 and CentOS 7.X

Comment: Related problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/sikuli/+bug/1506359

Comment: Another related one: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/272434

Answer (score 1):

Try to install it by

```
sudo apt install wmctrl
```

happy sikuling!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't run because `wmctrl` expects a window manager.
Demostration:

```
$ wmctrl -m
Cannot get window manager info properties.
(_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK or _WIN_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK)
```

Solution is simple:

```
$ yum instal icewm
$ icewm&
$ wmctrl -m
Name: IceWM 1.3.8 (Linux 4.3.0-1.fc24.x86_64/x86_64)
Class: N/A
PID: 15972
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: N/A
```

[IceWM](http://www.icewm.org/) is a lightweight window manager.

Credits: thanks Ramandeep Singh for providing me the clue. :-)

Comment: Thanks you man.l I try to run electron application inside docker container, icewm fix my issue