# How to get sikuli to run background jobs on one Windows machine

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation, sikuli

In the normal situation, Sikuli scripts use the machine's screen, mouse and keyboard, so while a script is running, the machine may not be used.

[In this other Sikuli question about headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032706/how-to-get-sikuli-working-in-headless-mode/26032780#26032780), a virtual screen is added to a second (headless) machine so that Sikuli scripts can operate there.

This question is about doing it *all on one machine*. Has a specific software stack and configuration been defined that (presumably) utilizes the same or similar techniques<sup>*</sup> such that a single Windows 7 machine can initiate a Sikuli script (using an alternate screen, keyboard, mouse combination) and still allow the "real" screen, keyboard and mouse to be used concurrently with the running script.

<sup>*  <sub>virtual screen and/or both VNC client and server on the same machine, etc.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

as I know you cannot do that. The only way to do that is to have virtual machine and run your sikuli script inside that virtual machine. That way, you can still use your host screen, keyboard and mouse normally. Hope this helps.

Comment: So the "specific software stack" that utilizes some kind of virtual machine to drive Sikuli, exists?  The best answer would include details of the software stack and a pointer to where more information on using the stack with Sikuli would be.