# SikuliX working image recognition not working in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, sikuli

I'm working on a RPA solution using SikuliX. It works quite well on my local PC (although when testing same script on another -but identical- computer there are some issues with image recognition).

The worst part is trying to get it working in a headless mode. I've started using VirtualBox (raising Windows 7 IE11 with vagrant) and tried the same script as before. Here image recognition is not working at all: matching preview renders bad results no matter what similarity coefficient I use.

Of course, I am aware of this topic: [How to get Sikuli working in headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032706/how-to-get-sikuli-working-in-headless-mode) and changed resolution using TightVNC.

I have read about some people having success using a Windows box, but I wonder how they got it working. There is no information aside from the above provided link.

Best regards.

Comment: Not sure what have you tried. Have you followed the steps provided in the link and it doesn't work for you?

Comment: I've been able to change resolution and start Sikuli IDE on the VM but, just like **Saba Ahang Dec 7 '14 at 22:20** stated on a comment, image recognition doesn't work as before, as it does in my local PC.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: Sorry, I changed my role in my company and no longer worked on this. Maybe my successor has more information, I will ask him.